# How to get the latest change time of a resource instance in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

In the case of `Deployment` in kubernetes, the service image may be updated iteratively, so the instance will be `updated constantly`. How do I get the `last update date`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? Some objects in kubernetes (like pods, deploys, replicasets) have `status` field. You can see it by `kubectl get xxx yyy -o jsonpath={.status} | jq`. Moving forward. You mentioned a deployment. It has deploy itself and a child - `replicaset` which is changed when image is changed. This `lastUpdateTime` you can easily get by `kubectl get deploy NAME -o jsonpath={.status.conditions[1].lastUpdateTime}`

Comment: I'm actually building the CRD Operator using `kubebuilder`, and I'll probably update the CR multiple times, and I'd like to be able to use the lastupdatetime to do something else. I discovered `Managed Fields` through `kubectl Describe CRD CR`, which seems to reflect the updated change, and I would like to be able to get confirmation or some other way to get the last update time

Answer (score 1):

You could query the api-server to get the last updated time. Please follow doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/.

UpdatedTime will be available in the `'.metadata.managedFields[].time'` of the json object returned by api server. You can then use any of the available json tool such as jq to extract the last updated value.

For example, I had a scenario, where I wish to check the last updated time of a k8s secret 'abc', present in namespace 'secret-test'.

Here How I got it:

```
Using kubectl proxy

1. kubectl proxy - makes my apiserver available @ 127.0.0.1:8001
2. curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/secret-test/secrets/abc | jq .metadata.managedFields[].time - gives list of all the times
3. curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/ambu/deployments/ambu | jq '[.metadata.managedFields[].time] | unique | sort | reverse | .[0]' - Using jq tool to extract only lastest/last updated time
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the resource/object.

In this particular case if you can rely on the fact that the only changes to a pod were caused by a deployment update (by updating one of it's container's image), then you can likely use the values from doing a `kubectl describe` on the deployment where you'll see something like the following values:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-12-29T14:53:50Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-12-29T14:53:51Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-12-29T14:53:51Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-12-29T14:53:50Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
```

You'd have to scrape out the latest value from those conditions. It's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: I appreciate that you spent some time answering the problem, but the answer itself doesn't contain the requested information. The `lastTransitionTime` ("Timestamp for when the Pod last transitioned from one status to another.") is not equal to the latest change time. Pods can transit from a status to status for many reasons unrelated to changes _intentionally_ triggered by a `kubectl` command or an API request. Which means, that we cannot rely on the field when looking for an updated object. The only reasonable part of your answer is actually "It depends on the resource", which is not useful.

Comment: It doesn't contain the requested information yes but it is still likely helpful in most cases considering it has 3k views on the question.